# how to create a CTF box and how to organize it

Tags: configuration

I want to create CTF (capture the flag) box for my assignments. I don’t have any idea about this. Can anyone help and guide me?

Comment: You do not provide any details at all for us to help. What kind of CTF? What kind of box? What assignments? What might you need to organise? What are your resources? What are your constraints? Is this a security question or a virtualisation question? Imagine that you are talking to the perfect person in the world who can answer your question. What details might they need to provide the perfect answer? "I want a box. Please help." isn't even close to the level of detail required.